# How to save drawn points on a QWidget in a list?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qpainter

I'm new to Qtcreator and I'm trying to draw some points on a widget. With the code I have it just works fine and I can draw as many points as I want the problem is though that if I cover my widget with another window and then show my widget again than I only get the last point I drew. Can some please tell me how I can solve this problem so I can always have all the points there that I drew.

Thanks in advance

```
void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    point=e->pos();
    update();
}
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);
    QPainter painter(this);
    QPen linepen(Qt::red);
    linepen.setCapStyle(Qt::RoundCap);
    linepen.setWidth(30);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing,true);
    painter.setPen(linepen);
    painter.drawPoint(point);
}
```

Comment: When your widget reapears it runs `paintEvent` and it seems your point is a global variable. So it is repainted with only the last additional point. You'd have to store points in `QVector` and paint them all.

Comment: can u please give me an example how to do that. thanks

Comment: check Marek's answer (he uses list instead of vector, but the general idea is the same)

Comment: i did but i just dont get the part with : for (auto point : points) sorry im totally new to programming

Comment: oh, that's an foreach loop from C++11 standard. You can replace it with usual `for(int i=0;i<points.size();i++){painter.drawPoint(points[i]);}`

Answer (score 3):

```
void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    // points is a "QList<QPoint> points;"
    points.append(e->pos());
    update();
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);
    QPainter painter(this);
    QPen linepen(Qt::red);
    linepen.setCapStyle(Qt::RoundCap);
    linepen.setWidth(30);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing,true);
    painter.setPen(linepen);
    for (auto point : points) {
        painter.drawPoint(point);
    }
}
```